# como eliminar versión 5.4 laravel

Tags: php, laravel, windows, composer

buenas tardes disculpen, me podrían decir como eliminar mi versión `5.4` de `laravel`, pasa que por un tema de proyectos necesito trabajar con la `5.2`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

he visto que algunos cambian el require en el `composer.json`, pero segun el composer tengo la `5.2`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ya hiciste un `composer update`?

Answer (score 0):

Vas a gastar mucho tiempo, por lo que recomendaria que hicieras uno nuevo en 5.2 y pasarlo

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel nombreproyecto "5.2.*"
```

Si aun asi quieres hacer downgrade, prueba a cambiar en `composer.json`

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
```

y ahora haz un `composer update`